# Error reading a binary file into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to insert values in a `.bin` file to an array. However, at the first line I get the error message:

> ```
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xdd\xb9\xa8\tLv\x1e\xc0\x9b\xd0C\xb0\n'
> ```

Here is the code:

```
import os 
import numpy as np
def readdata():
  filename1 = "data.bin"
  f1 = open (filename1,'rb')

f1stat = os.stat(filename1)

count = f1stat.st_size

data = np.zeros((5,count), dtype= np.float)

for i in range(5):
  for j in range(count):
      data[i][j] = f1.readline()
```

Comment: How many values are there per line in your input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually directly read the binary file into a numpy array by using `np.fromfile` and setting the data type to the length of your integer in bits, for example, `uint32`

```
f1 = open(filename1,'rb')
data = np.fromfile(f1, dtype=np.uint32)
```

You can read more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html)

Comment: somehow solved the error, could you explain why ?